# Simple Hierarchical Select starting at vocabularies

Tags: 8, views

I am using Simple [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module with my Drupal 8 site. What I want to do with this module is in view, I want to allow choosing one of vocabularies first, and second dropdown will show up with a list of terms of selected vocabulary.

Basically, Simple Hierarchical Select module requires selecting vocabulary first when creating an exposed filter. But, I want clients to be able to choose vocabulary first then terms.

Based on my question, is there any way to do so with this module or other modules?

Thank you, in advance.